# Unable to connect to Docker in Docker

Tags: docker

I followed the instructions provided at https://docs.docker.com/samples/docker/, i.e.

```
docker run --privileged --name some-docker -d docker:dind
```

However, I can't connect to the docker service.

```
docker run -i -t --rm --link some-docker:docker docker:latest version       

Client:
 Version:      17.06.0-ce
 API version:  1.30
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   02c1d87
 Built:        Fri Jun 23 21:15:15 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://docker:2375. Is the docker daemon running?
```

I'm able to telnet when I open a terminal via

```
docker run -i -t --rm --link some-docker:docker docker:latest /bin/sh

/ # telnet docker 2375
l
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Connection: close

400 Bad RequestConnection closed by foreign host
```

Running `docker -H docker info` in the same container results in:

```
docker -H docker info
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://docker:2375. Is the docker daemon running?
```

If however I build a ubuntu based docker with docker installed using the following `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install \
  apt-transport-https \
  ca-certificates \
  curl \
  software-properties-common

RUN curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | apt-key add -

RUN add-apt-repository \
  "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
  $(lsb_release -cs) \
  stable"

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install docker-ce
```

I'm able to connect to the docker-in-docker:

```
docker build -t docker-ubuntu .
docker run -i -t --rm --link some-docker:docker docker-ubuntu:latest /bin/sh
# docker -H docker info
Containers: 0
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 0
Server Version: 17.06.0-ce
Storage Driver: vfs
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: cfb82a876ecc11b5ca0977d1733adbe58599088a
runc version: 2d41c047c83e09a6d61d464906feb2a2f3c52aa4
init version: 949e6fa
Security Options:
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.9.27-moby
Operating System: Alpine Linux v3.6 (containerized)
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 2
Total Memory: 1.952GiB
Name: b39967739fb9
ID: NDIF:PU7X:NA4B:IMI4:UH7V:VL4G:Q6L5:DPKP:NKDH:2XH6:XYDB:F2AV
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
No Proxy: *.local, 169.254/16
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: bridge-nf-call-iptables is disabled
WARNING: bridge-nf-call-ip6tables is disabled
```

I tried both on docker-ce for Mac OS X as well as docker-ce for Ubuntu. Same result. Any ideas?

Comment: The first two commands work like a charm in my OSX. Try to update your base images to discard some versioning problem: `docker pull docker:dind && docker pull docker:latest`

Comment: Thx @Robert. I already had the latest images, but apparently my Docker for Mac was lagging 1 version behind. After updating it and resetting everything it now works. On ubuntu it still doesn't work. The docker version is the latest. Even after erasing /var/lib/docker completely, the problem still persists

Answer (score 0):

--privileged does not mean you have access to the docker-socket, but rather all devices /dev and more.

That said, be sure to volume mount the docker-socket into your container

`docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock`

or analog with docker-compose.yml

Comment: He is trying to use docker-in-docker image (dind). Mounting the docker.sock of the host only will give access to that docker, but he is trying to start a new docker (docker in docker)